# If everything is decreed in our life already then what's the point of making Dua?

Tags: dua, qadar

I read somewhere that only Dua can change the qadr and it is always encouraged to make Dua to Allah for every need, in every situation. But today I have learnt some mufti saying there are two types of qadr, ones that are absolute like time of birth,death n marriage. And these cannot be changed through Dua. Then if a person say for example, make Dua for a long life what would happen? Or, if a person makes Dua to marry a certain person/ person with certain qualities would that have no effect? I mean if these things falls under the category of absolute qadr on which Dua has no effect then why should people make Dua about them?

Comment: As you said, everything is already decreed. This means you making the duas was decreed and it will only be answered if Allah wishes to.

Answer (score -1):

I think everything falls under absolute qadr which is written in Loh-e-Mahfooz with Allah (SWT). Which is your birth, death, rizq, siblings, spouse, kids and the main events that pretty much everybody agrees too but my personal opinion is that i think everybody's QADR is like a tree with a lot of branches and at the end of every branch is a fruit. There is a trunk in the middle that has a fruit at the end too. The fruit is the death which we have to get no matter what. The branches are the routes we take to get to the fruit of death the trunk is the right way which ALLAH (SWT) wants us to take but when we don't do that, then ALLAH (SWT) already knows that we will do this because of the free will so ALLAH (SWT) already decided if i do this then the result and consequences will be this and so on. 
Means all the angles of each and everybody's life is already written and decided, all the aspects of life are all decided we are just highlighting the path we are taking to get to the end.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe what is **pre-destined** is supposed to be in consequence of your **Dua'a**!